# JSON nested objects wep app

Tags: ajax, json, wordpress, jquery-mobile

So I'm trying to program a Web App (later hyprid app via Phonegap) which has Wordpress has backend (information will be dynamically load through json api)

But I'm stuck at the first step.

I want a menu where like this

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

and the single categories link to the posts in the categorie

Here is a part of my json

```
{
"status": "ok",
"count": 10,
"count_total": 20,
"pages": 2,
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 86,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "inaktiviert",
        "url": "http://localhost/wordpress/?p=86",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Inaktiviert",
        "title_plain": "Inaktiviert",
        "content": "<p>Das Feature ist inaktiviert.</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>Das Feature ist inaktiviert.</p>\n",
        "date": "2014-03-04 15:09:51",
        "modified": "2014-03-04 15:09:51",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "slug": "symbole-fuer-verschiedene-ereignisse",
                "title": "Symbole für verschiedene Ereignisse",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 4
            }
        ],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "admin",
            "name": "admin",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "admin",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "custom_fields": {}
    },
    {
        "id": 84,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "kann-nicht-aktualisiert-werden",
        "url": "http://localhost/wordpress/?p=84",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "kann nicht aktualisiert werden",
        "title_plain": "kann nicht aktualisiert werden",
        "content": "<p>Das Feature kann nicht aktualisiert werden, der Fehler kann über das Fehlermanagement bzw. über Bearbeiten behoben werden.</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>Das Feature kann nicht aktualisiert werden, der Fehler kann über das Fehlermanagement bzw. über Bearbeiten behoben werden.</p>\n",
        "date": "2014-03-04 15:09:25",
        "modified": "2014-03-04 15:09:25",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "slug": "symbole-fuer-verschiedene-ereignisse",
                "title": "Symbole für verschiedene Ereignisse",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 4
            }
        ],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "admin",
            "name": "admin",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "admin",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "custom_fields": {}
    },


    {
        "id": 78,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "das-braune-zahnrad",
        "url": "http://localhost/wordpress/?p=78",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Das braune Zahnrad",
        "title_plain": "Das braune Zahnrad",
        "content": "<p>Das braune Zahnrad und der rote Blitz zeigen an, dass die Teilereferenz kontextabhängig ist und dass dieses Exemplar nicht in der Teiledefinition verwendet wird. Dieses Kontextteil kann bearbeitet werden. Dieses Symbol wird möglicherweise angezeigt, wenn ein Kontextteil in ein anderes CATProduct kopiert/eingefügt wird, ohne dabei die Kon-textverknüpfungen zu berücksichtigen</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>Das braune Zahnrad und der rote Blitz zeigen an, dass die Teilereferenz kontextabhängig ist und dass dieses Exemplar nicht in der Teiledefinition verwendet wird. Dieses Kontextteil kann bearbeitet werden. Dieses Symbol wird möglicherweise angezeigt, wenn ein Kontextteil in ein anderes CATProduct kopiert/eingefügt wird, ohne dabei die Kon-textverknüpfungen zu berücksichtigen</p>\n",
        "date": "2014-03-04 15:07:23",
        "modified": "2014-03-04 15:07:29",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "slug": "symbole-fuer-kontextteile",
                "title": "Symbole für Kontextteile",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 3
            }
        ],
```

I tried to start programming but as I am a newbie in programming with ajax js I'm kinda lost

Here is my code I started writing, but it doesnt't show anything:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var liste = $('#liste');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/?json=1',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success:
                 function(daten) {
                     var data = $.parseJSON(daten)
                    $.each(daten.categories, function(index, datensatz) {
                        $('<li><a href="#page' + datensatz.id + '">' + datensatz.title + '</a></li>').appendTo(liste);
                        $('<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="page' + datensatz.id + '"><div data-role="header"><h1>' + 
                        datensatz.title + '</h1></div><div data-role="content">' + datensatz.content + '</div></div>').appendTo('body');
                    });
                    liste.listview("refresh");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you get if you just visit `http://localhost/wordpress/?json=1` in your browser?

Comment: Possibly you want `daten.posts.categories` instead of `daten.categories` because `categories` is further nested in

Comment: @Stewart I get the whole json from my wordpress content.
I tried `daten.posts.categories` too, but nothing.
If I use only `daten.posts` it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Looks like `daten.posts` is an array, so you need to iterate that to get `categories` I guess.

Comment: And how do I do that? Sorry, I'm a total beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON, `posts` is an array of objects each of which contains a property called `categories` which is also an array of objects.  So you $.each() should iterate over posts, and then within the each you need to iterate categories.  You could do it like this:

```
var liste = $('#liste');

var AllListItems = '';
var AllDynamicPages = '';
$.each(daten.posts, function(index1, datensatz) {
    var postid = datensatz.id;
    var postTitle = datensatz.title;
    var postContent = datensatz.content;

    for (var i = 0; i< datensatz.categories.length; i++) {
        var catid = datensatz.categories[i].id;     
        var catTitle = datensatz.categories[i].title;            
        AllListItems += '<li><a href="#page' + catid + '">' + catTitle + '</a></li>';    
        AllDynamicPages += '<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="page' + catid + '"><div data-role="header"><h1>' + catTitle + '</h1></div><div data-role="content">' + postContent + '</div></div>'
    }        
});

liste.empty().append(AllListItems).listview("refresh");
$("body").append(AllDynamicPages);
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nn5Rw/1/)**

NOTE: it is not clear from your JSON whether you really want the category ID which is not unique accross posts or the post id.  So you will probably need to tweak the code to show the correct output...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!
Last really silly question: how do I include a external JSON file (trough url)?
Tried for like an hour. :(

Comment: FYI: I want a distinct list of categories, that leads to a list of all posts of the categorie. And the list of the posts lead to the content.

Comment: If the JSON is coming from an external web service, you would make an AJAX call to the appropriate URL, and it would return the JSON. To get distinct categories with lists of posts per category, you would probably want to iterate once and create a new object that looks something like : [{"category": "cat name", "posts":[{post info},{post info},{post info}] }, {next category}, etc.   ]. Each category could be a collapsible containing a list of its posts. You should probably post a new question if you need help with this...